# Meaning of Error Term e

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, data-mining, data-modeling, supervised-learning

I was reading the book "Introduction to Statistical Learning". The book says that:

More generally, suppose that we observe a quantitative response Y and a set of predictor variables X1, X2, .... Xn.

We assume that there is some relationship between Y and X (X1, X2, ... Xn) which can be written in the very general form as:

Y = f(X) + e

Here, f is some fixed but unknown function of X and e is a random error term which is independent of X and has mean zero.

I want to know what does it mean to have zero mean ?

Comment: It seems that e is essentially noise (e.g. in measurement), so as the number of observations tends very large / toward infinity, e will average out to zero.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what does it mean to have zero mean ?

It means, that `e`, treated as a random variable has expected value of 0. In other words if you compute average of these errors, then with the sample set growing to infinity - it will converge to zero.

In more practical terms it simply means, that your noise does not change your f(x) function, but so if you observe some "positive" noise, there was exact same probability of observing "negative" noise of the same strength. Notice, that if you have `e` with mean `m` this would mean that

```
E[f(x) + e] = E[f(x)] + E[e] = E[f(x)] + m
```

thus for every single point "x" you would expect to observe value  f(x) +  m instead of just f(x). Thus it would be the same as modelling

```
g(x) + e'
```

where

```
g(x) = f(x) + m
```

and `e'` is now zero-mean random noise. Thus the whole statistical setting is still valid for non-zero mean noise, but then your task (that ML is solving) is not to model "f" but "g" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say for illustration that your errors are normally distributed, since in introductory settings we often make that assumption. If you're willing to accept that, then another way of thinking about zero mean error is to say that your outcome variable Y is itself a random variable that is distributed like N(f(X),sigma^2). In other words, the outcome is like a random draw from some probability distributed that is centered at f(X). Note that if you have different Xs for each Y observed, then you'll see that the value of f(X) changes, and so the normal distribution that generates each observed outcome Y changes too.  Yet all the observations are tied together by that basic rule (f) about how features (i.e. your X data) got assigned to the distributions that generated your outcomes.